# Pandas: How do I drop any rows with the same unique ID IF any of those rows contain a specific value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set that has a list of unique IDs with corresponding data, but some unique ID's have multiple rows.

What I am trying to do is drop all rows with the same unique ID IF any of those rows contain a single/multiple instances of a specific value.

example DF:

```
ID      %       Trump Adj
abc123  0.833   Moron
xyz987  0.87    Loser
abc123  0.867   Puppet
abc123  0.812   Incompentent
hij456  0.812   Moron
lmn789  0.837   Senile 
lmn789  0.856   Opposite of Obama
lmn789  0.813   Embarrassing
```

I would like to drop any rows that contain 'Moron' in the 'Trump Adj' column as well as any other rows that share the same ID.

result DF:

```
ID      %       Trump Adj
xyz987  0.87    Loser
lmn789  0.837   Senile 
lmn789  0.856   Opposite of Obama
lmn789  0.813   Embarrassing
```

Any help or direction would be very helpful, and please let me know if there needs to be further clarification!

Comment: Check `drop_duplicates` and `.str.contains`

Answer (score 1):

Using **`str.contains`** and a boolean mask:

```
df[~df['ID'].isin(df.loc[df.TrumpAdj.str.contains('Moron'), 'ID'].unique())]

       ID      %         TrumpAdj
1  xyz987  0.870            Loser
5  lmn789  0.837           Senile
6  lmn789  0.856  OppositeofObama
7  lmn789  0.813     Embarrassing
```

***Explanation***

First, find columns that contain the word `'Moron'`:

```
df.TrumpAdj.str.contains('Moron')

0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5    False
6    False
7    False
Name: TrumpAdj, dtype: bool
```

Then, find the unique `ID`'s that have adjectives that contain the word `Moron`:

```
df.loc[df.TrumpAdj.str.contains('Moron'), 'ID'].unique()
# array(['abc123', 'hij456'], dtype=object)
```

Finally, locate all rows where `'ID'` is *not* found in the list we just created:

```
df[~df['ID'].isin(df.loc[df.TrumpAdj.str.contains('Moron'), 'ID'].unique())]
```

Which gives us our desired outcome.

Comment: This was super helpful and the explanation was much appreciated! Thank you!!

Comment: Glad to help, happy programming!

Answer (score 1):

You can set the index to `ID`, and then use `drop`:

```
df.set_index('ID', inplace=True)

df.drop(df.loc[df['Trump Adj'] == 'Moron'].index)

            %          Trump Adj
ID                              
xyz987  0.870              Loser
lmn789  0.837             Senile
lmn789  0.856  Opposite of Obama
lmn789  0.813       Embarrassing
```

If wanted, you can also reset the index after this to get `ID` back as a column:

```
df.drop(df.loc[df['Trump Adj'] == 'Moron'].index).reset_index()

       ID      %          Trump Adj
0  xyz987  0.870              Loser
1  lmn789  0.837             Senile
2  lmn789  0.856  Opposite of Obama
3  lmn789  0.813       Embarrassing
```